# Cannot set yandex bem filter in emmet (sublime text-3)

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3, emmet, bem

When im trying to set bem filter in emmet user settings:

```
"preferences": {
    "bem.elementSeparator": "__",
    "bem.modifierSeparator": "_",
    "bem.shortElementPrefix": "-"
}
```

I always get error:

```
Error trying to parse settings
```

How can I solve this problem?